# execute a SQL or PL/SQL code after html insert action in APEX

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, plsql, oracle-apex

i have a region in apex that contains a list of options to select

```
htp.p('
<form>
<select multiple width="100%" style="width: 100%; height: 80%;">   
  ');
for a in 
(select id_plan, year_plan from plan)
loop
  htp.p('
<option value="'||htf.escape_sc(a.id_plan)||'">'||htf.escape_sc(a.year_plan)||'</option> 
end loop;
htp.p('</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
');
```

how can i get back the select value(s) and execute an SQL insert action for each one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use Apex, why don't you use its **Select List** item (and allow multiple choices)?

Doing so, values you select would be colon-separated (e.g. `10:20:30`).

In order to insert those values into a table, a simple option is to create a button and a process which fires when that button is pressed. As button **submits** the page, selected value(s) are stored into session state and process *sees* them.

If that select list item's name is `P1_LIST`, process would be e.g.

```
insert into some_table (col) 
select regexp_substr(:P1_LIST, '[^:]+', 1, level)
  from dual
  connect by level <= regexp_count(:P1_LIST, ':') + 1
```

Comment: that's what i did at first, but the choices to select from are too many and must be grouped in 5 or so layers, i know i can group the options in an Apex select list but only one group parent is allowed.